# Counting permutations of up to k elements

Tags: combinatorics

Given a set of $n$ elements, I want to count all permutations with repetition, from $1$ to $k$ elements ($k>2$). In other words, $n^k+n^{k-1}+…+n^1$. What's the term/notation for this operation? Thanks!

Comment: Right… I see I've actually made it more confusing. I meant $n^k$.

Answer (score 0):

The number of permuations of $k$ elements from an $n$-element set is often written as $P(n,k)$ or $_nP_k$. Or you could be more straightforward and write $\dfrac{n!}{(n-k)!}$.

Comment: The OP is allowing repetitions (so he is actually counting "words" or "strings," not "permutations").